# How can I pick a contact phone number in iOS?

Tags: ios, cncontactpicker

I know how to pick a contact in iOS (using the CNContactPickerViewController), but how can I pick a specific phone number for a contact, instead of the contact itself, as a whole? That should be possible, according to the docs, but I didn't find out how.

EDIT: here's my code

```
CNContactPickerViewController *contactPicker = [[CNContactPickerViewController alloc] init];

contactPicker.delegate = self;
contactPicker.displayedPropertyKeys = @[CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactImageDataAvailableKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactThumbnailImageDataKey, CNContactIdentifierKey];

[self presentViewController:contactPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

So, I do set the displayedProperties, but the result is the same, even if I choose only CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, I'm not presented with all contact's numbers so that I can choose a speicific number.

What am I missing?

EDIT 2: the callback methods, as requested. I don't know of what significance they are, but nevertheless.

```
-(void) contactPicker:(CNContactPickerViewController *)picker didSelectContact:(CNContact *)contact{
  //NSLog(@"Contact : %@",contact);
  NSString* contactName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", contact.givenName, @" ", contact.familyName];
  [currentButton setTitle:contactName forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [currentName setText:contactName];
...
}

-(void) contactPickerDidCancel:(CNContactPickerViewController *)picker {
  //NSLog(@"Cancelled");
}
```

Comment: each contact has an array of phone numbers, search through the array to select a specific phone number

Comment: Well, I could also search through an array of contacts and select a specific one, but it's much more helpful to have the picker. In Android you can pick a number, and according to the docs, the same goes for iOS too, I read in the docs: "The CNContactPicker object displays the popover-based system interface for selecting a contact. The methods and properties of this class help you choose a contact or a contact's value, such as a phone number or email address, of a contact."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, here's the answer:

First of all, use only the property that you want to select in the `displayedPropertyKeys` (in this case that is `CNContactPhoneNumbersKey`), and make sure to implement ALL delegate methods (i.e. both `didSelectContact` - when the contact has only one phone number, and `didSelectContactProperty` - when the contact has more than one phone number).

Furhtermore, restrict the contact selection by setting:

```
contactPicker.predicateForEnablingContact = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"phoneNumbers.@count > 0"];
contactPicker.predicateForSelectionOfContact = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"phoneNumbers.@count == 1"];
contactPicker.predicateForSelectionOfProperty = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"key == 'phoneNumbers'"];
```

Comment: Thanks Eir. It still does not work in my case. I have a very simple code here:
        contactPicker = [[CNContactPickerViewController alloc] init];
        [contactPicker setDisplayedPropertyKeys:@[CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]];
and then I do the predicate like you said. But I get an error for the last predicateForSelectionOfProperty that says " Error Domain=CNErrorDomain Code=400 \"Invalid Predicate\" UserInfo={CNKeyPaths=(\n    phoneNumber\n), NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid Predicate"

I've tried making it phoneNumbers, it still gives me the same error 'Invalid predicate'

Comment: I also tried this predicate with an apostrophe i.e. [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"key == 'phoneNumber'"], with this the Invalid predicate error goes away, but my selection is still not based on property, it is based on contacts.
It feels like I must be missing some other piece, I've verified that I have the delegate set properly and am also implementing didSelectContacts and didSelectContactProperties (I want multiple selection).

Comment: What I posted is working code. Maybe you have a typo somewhere? Or you're targeting an old iOS version?

Comment: @Pankaj - I confirm this code works. (Thanks!) I'm using it to pick the emailAddresses, but I think I've spotted why yours isn't working. Try `contactPicker.predicateForSelectionOfProperty = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"key == 'phoneNumbers'"];`. The key names are [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cncontact?language=objc).

Comment: Doesn't work for me, only the pick contact gets called (not the pick property one) and also I can't get it to display the phone numbers. Strange, I know it should work! I am using Swift 4 FYI

Comment: Addind to KutakMir's comments, I also can't get this to work. Implemented as show, it locks out any contact with more than one phone number from selection. What I want is for those contacts to display all their numbers and have the user pick one of them and return it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `displayedKeys` property of the `CNContactPicker`. If you don't set any keys, you can only select a contact. If you set the keys, then you choose a contact then you select a desired contact property.

Implement the appropriate delegate methods to complete the process.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am setting the displayedPropertyKeys, but without success. I posted my code, maybe you could spot the problem?

Comment: Have you implemented the proper delegate methods? Update your question with the delegate methods you have implemented. BTW - your question states you are using `CNContactPicker` but your code shows you using `CNContactPickerViewController`.

Comment: I posted the implementation of the delegate methods. What's the difference in regard to this problem between using the CNContactPicker and CNContactPickerViewController ? Both claim to have the option to pick a contact property and both take the same arguments.

Comment: I completed your answer, in order to mark it as the accepted answer. It was lacking quite a bit, but it was in the right direction.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same, the accepted answer and the comments are not clear what the solution is. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Pankaj I posted the full solution, as my changes to the above answer were rejected.