# Selecting multiple contacts/contact properties in CNContactPicker

Tags: ios, swift, cncontactpicker

I'm using the predicates defined here: 
[How can I pick a contact phone number in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41622979/how-can-i-pick-a-contact-phone-number-in-ios/42256751#42256751?newreg=c2f446161b964913a3989fd944f29580).

```
contactsPicker.predicateForEnablingContact = NSPredicate(format:"phoneNumbers.@count > 0")
contactsPicker.predicateForSelectionOfContact = NSPredicate(format: "phoneNumbers.@count == 1")
contactsPicker.displayedPropertyKeys = [CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]
```

I have also defined the following delegate methods:

```
func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController,
                   didSelect contactProperty: CNContactProperty) {
    print(contactProperty)
}

func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contact: CNContact) {
    print(contact)
}
```

The behaviour I expect is that the user gets to pick the phone number properties from multiple different contacts and when the user clicks done, I get a list of these properties and contacts.

Unfortunately, the code above exits the picker immediately when the user clicks done. This means the user cannot select multiple phone numbers and/or multiple contacts and can only select one before the picker exits.

How can I change it so that it selects multiple properties or contacts and submits on clicking on done?

Answer (score 0):

In order to select more than one contact property you need to define `contactPicker:didSelectContactProperties:` in your delegate instead of the methods you mentioned in your question.

Hope this helps!

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contactsui/cncontactpickerdelegate/1619202-contactpicker)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement multi-selection of contact then you need to implement `CNContactPickerViewController`'s delegate i.e.`CNContactPickerDelegate` in your view controller, so it will automatically configure `CNContactPickerViewController` for multi-selection.

```
- (void)contactPicker:(CNContactPickerViewController *)picker didSelectContact:(CNContact *)contact;
- (void)contactPicker:(CNContactPickerViewController *)picker didSelectContactProperty:(CNContactProperty *)contactProperty;
```

If you want to allow user to select a contact only then you need to implement following methods...

```
- (void)contactPicker:(CNContactPickerViewController *)picker didSelectContacts:(NSArray<CNContact*> *)contacts;
- (void)contactPicker:(CNContactPickerViewController *)picker didSelectContactProperties:(NSArray<CNContactProperty*> *)contactProperties;
```

Don't implement single selection and multi-selection delegate methods at same time.

**NOTE: Implementing one of these methods will configure the picker for multi-selection.**